# XSL-FO fails to add font in java

Tags: java, xml, spring, xslt, xsl-fo

I am trying to use the font "Frankling Gothic Medium" in my pdf generation.
But I seem not to be able to get it into java/FOP factory.

I've tried without setting autoconfig.
But Right now my config looks like this:

"Error":

```
2014-05-26 09:39:53.577  WARN 7048 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent          : Font "Franklin Gothic Medium,normal,400" not found. Substituting with "any,normal,400".
2014-05-26 09:39:53.623  WARN 7048 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent          : Font "Symbol,normal,700" not found. Substituting with "Symbol,normal,400".
2014-05-26 09:39:53.623  WARN 7048 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent          : Font "ZapfDingbats,normal,700" not found. Substituting with "ZapfDingbats,normal,400".
2014-05-26 09:39:53.625  WARN 7048 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent          : Font "Franklin Gothic Medium,normal,700" not found. Substituting with "any,normal,700".
```

XML:

```
<fop version="1.0">
    <renderers>
        <renderer mime="application/pdf">
            <fonts>
                <!-- automatically detect operating system installed fonts -->
                <auto-detect />
                <!-- register all the fonts found in a directory -->
                <directory>C:\workspace\pathToTTF</directory>
            </fonts>
        </renderer>
    </renderers>
</fop>
```

JAVA:

```
    DefaultConfigurationBuilder cfgBuilder = new DefaultConfigurationBuilder();
    URL dir_url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("dk/print/services/mycfg.xml");
    Configuration cfg = cfgBuilder.buildFromFile(new File(dir_url.toURI()));
    FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();
    FopFactoryConfigurator fopFacConf = new FopFactoryConfigurator(fopFactory);
    fopFacConf.setUserConfig(cfg);
    User user = userRepository.getUser();
    String quoteXML = new PrintQuote(quote, user).asXML();

    try {
        Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop("application/pdf", out);
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Source xslt = new StreamSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream("quote.xsl"));
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);

        Source src = new StreamSource(IOUtils.toInputStream(quoteXML));

        Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
        transformer.transform(src, res);

    } finally {
        // Clean-up
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
    }
```

XML suggested(translated to my font):

```
<fop version="1.0">
    <renderers>
        <renderer mime="application/pdf">
            <fonts>
                <font embed-url="framd.ttf" kerning="yes" sub-font="Franklin Gothic">
                    <font-triplet name="Franklin Gothic Medium" style="normal"
                        weight="normal" />
                </font>
                <font embed-url="FRAHV.TTF" kerning="yes" sub-font="Franklin Gothic">
                    <font-triplet name="Franklin Gothic Heavy" style="normal"
                        weight="bold" />
                </font>
            </fonts>
        </renderer>
    </renderers>
</fop>
```

Still same kind of error:

```
2014-05-26 10:34:12.440  WARN 7224 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent          : Font "Franklin Gothic Medium,normal,400" not found. Substituting with "any,normal,400".
2014-05-26 10:34:12.440  WARN 7224 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent          : Font "Franklin Gothic,normal,400" not found. Substituting with "any,normal,400".
2014-05-26 10:34:12.485  WARN 7224 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent          : Font "Symbol,normal,700" not found. Substituting with "Symbol,normal,400".
2014-05-26 10:34:12.487  WARN 7224 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent          : Font "ZapfDingbats,normal,700" not found. Substituting with "ZapfDingbats,normal,400".
2014-05-26 10:34:12.489  WARN 7224 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent          : Font "Franklin Gothic Medium,normal,700" not found. Substituting with "any,normal,700".
2014-05-26 10:34:12.489  WARN 7224 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent          : Font "Franklin Gothic,normal,700" not found. Substituting with "any,normal,700".
```

Example of XSL definition:

Installations
                                        dato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I do it is

```
<renderer mime="application/pdf">
  <fonts>
    <font embed-url="MSMINCHO.TTF" kerning="yes" sub-font="MS Mincho">
    <font-triplet name="MS Mincho" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
    <font-triplet name="MS Mincho" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
    </font>
  </fonts>
</renderer>
```

Comment: And where do you have them then, just in normal system path ?

Comment: No in this situation I ship them with the web app.

Comment: How ? which folder do they auto detect it so you can embed-url="" ?

Comment: same folder as the xml

Comment: Added it to same folder, typed as above, updated Q with error, xml and xsl

Answer (score 2):

The way to do it is by adding the full URL, which in this case is the windows path.
The following gets rid of the `Font "Symbol,normal,700" not found.` error:

```
<fonts>
    <font embed-url="C:\Windows\Fonts\symbol.ttf" kerning="yes" sub-font="Symbol">
        <font-triplet name="Symbol" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
        <font-triplet name="Symbol" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
    </font>
</fonts>
```

Also make sure that `fop` is reading **your** configuration file, and not the template one.

```
fop -c fop.xconf -fo simple.fo -pdf simple.pdf
```

Comment: But I don't have access to full url when deploying to a server

Comment: Then try with a relative one.